# Problem using \ast several times in a row

Tags: symbols

I want to write

*, **, and *** denotes any significance at the 10%, 5%, and 1% level, respectively.

I use the following code:

```
{\ast}, {\ast}{\ast}, and {\ast}{\ast}{\ast} denotes any significance at the 10\%, 5\%, and 1\% level, respectively.
```

When i try that, it messes up the text.

Comment: surely you got an error `! Missing $ inserted`  on the first `\ast`  It is a math mode command and you have used it in text. Never look at the PDF after any error, it is not intended to be usable. use `$\ast$`, `$\ast\ast$ and $\ast{\ast}\ast$`

Comment: Or the longer text mode command `\textasteriskcentered`.